# current_cat_ancestor Alternatives

Tags: functions, categories

It looks like [adding current-cat-ancestor class to category list](http://wordpress.org/extend/ideas/topic/add-current-cat-ancestor-class-to-categoly-list) was proposed, but never implemented. The only way I've been able to find so far is to re-create the `wp_list_categories()` function entirely:

```
function wp_list_categories2($args = '') {
    global $cat;
    if($args == '')
        $wp_list_categories = wp_list_categories();
    else
        $wp_list_categories = wp_list_categories($args);

    $cat_id_cut1 = explode('cat-item-', $wp_list_categories);

    for($i=1; $i&lt;sizeof($cat_id_cut1); $i++) {
        $cat_id_cut2 = explode('"&gt;&lt;a', $cat_id_cut1[$i]);
        $category_id_array[] = $cat_id_cut2[0];
    }

    for($i=0; $i&lt;sizeof($category_id_array); $i++) {
        if(is_numeric($category_id_array[$i])) {
            if(cat_is_ancestor_of( $category_id_array[$i], $cat)) {
                $wp_list_categories = str_replace($category_id_array[$i], $category_id_array[$i] . ' current-cat-ancestor', $wp_list_categories);
            }
        }
    }
    return $wp_list_categories;
}
```

is there a better way around this? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is. Yours and Tom's answers are very similar in approach. The only alternative I can think of is to use a custom walker class - due to lack of filters that means reproducing the entire `start_el` - method and `walk` methods. I'm not sure that's much better...

Comment: Hey @StephenHarris appreciate the insight on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fumbling around with this for a bit, I realized I needed this to work with custom taxonomies, not just regular categories. I unfortunately couldn't use "all" of what either the  solution I found or Tom did, so I ended up writing my own. As long as you specify a `taxonomy` arg, you should be all set:

```
function add_category_ancestor_class($args) {
    $list_args = $args;
    $list_args['echo'] = '0';
    $catlist = wp_list_categories($list_args);
    if ( is_tax($list_args['taxonomy']) ) {
        global $wp_query;
        $term = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
        $term_object = get_term_by('id', $term->term_id, $list_args['taxonomy']);

        $current_term = $term->term_id;

        $ancestors = get_ancestors($current_term, $list_args['taxonomy']);

        // how many levels more than two set hierarchical ancestor?
        // count from 1 array from 0 : 1:0=Current 2:1=Parent >2:1 all Ancestors
        if( count($ancestors) >= 2){
            $max = count($ancestors) - 1; //Array elements zero based = count - 1
            $extra_class='current-cat-ancestor';
            for ( $counter = 1; $counter <= $max; $counter ++) {
                $cat_ancestor_class = 'cat-item cat-item-'. $ancestors[$counter];
                $amended_class = $cat_ancestor_class . ' ' . $extra_class;
                $catlist = str_replace($cat_ancestor_class, $amended_class, $catlist );
            }
        }
    }
    $menu = str_replace( array( "\r", "\n", "\t" ), '', $catlist );
    return $menu;
}
```

Really hoping this gets into WordPress at some point though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a simple way of hooking in, there may be if you dig deeper, and it's probably better to use a nav menu if you're dealing with a list that requires that kind of heirarchical navigation

If you're intersted in alternatives, I found a solution here:

http://brassblogs.com/code-snippets/add-current-category-ancestor-to-wp_list_categories

Here's a slightly modified version:

```
$args = array(
    'sort_column' =>'name',
    'sort_order' => 'asc',
    'style' =>'list',
    'depth' =>'0',
    'hierarchical' =>'true',
    'title_li' =>'0',
    'hide_empty' =>'1',
);
echo add_category_ancestor_class($args);

function add_category_ancestor_class($args) {    
    $list_args = $args;
    $list_args['echo'] = '0';
    $catlist = wp_list_categories($list_args);
    if ( is_category() ) {
        //Get the active category id
        global $cat;
        $curr_cat = get_category($cat);
        $catid = $curr_cat->cat_ID;
        //Find the top level id and number of levels    
        while ($catid){  
            $curr_cat = get_category($catid); 
            $catid = $curr_cat->category_parent; 
            $id[] = $curr_cat->cat_ID;          
        }
        //How many levels more than two set hierarchical ancestor?
        //Count from 1 array from 0 : 1:0=Current 2:1=Parent >2:1 all Ancestors
        if( count($id) > 2){
            $max=count($id)-1; //Array elements zero based = count - 1
            $extra_class='current-cat-ancestor';
            for ( $counter = 1; $counter <= $max; $counter ++) {
                $cat_ancestor_class = 'cat-item cat-item-'. $id[$counter];
                $amended_class = $cat_ancestor_class . ' ' . $extra_class;
                $catlist = str_replace($cat_ancestor_class, $amended_class, $catlist );
            }
        }
    }
    $menu = str_replace( array( "\r", "\n", "\t" ), '', $catlist );
    return $menu;
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate the response. My needs changed a little (answered above), but hopefully this will allow others to plug into what I've done above for their own needs as well. Thanks!